# How do I use SciKit's IterativeImputer on a three dimensional dataarray?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, interpolation, missing-data, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file that has a 3 dimensional variable with some missing values. I need to fill in the missing values before I can do further calculations (linear regression). I don't want to drop the values. When I tried using Scikit's Iterative Imputer, it gave me the following error:

**Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.**

This is a snippet of my code.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

ifile = xr.open_dataset('/path/to/file.nc')
hus = ifile.hus
imp = IterativeImputer(missing_values = 'nan')
imp.fit(ifile.hus)
```

I've also tried fit_transform, and I get the same error. hus is dependent on (time,lat,lon).